# Make single array outside for loop in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get "time availiablily" of every taxi according to "total taxi by user",
I have following two tables,

Here is my first table name is "taxiInfo"

```
id      userId          totalTaxi       
1       2               3
2       3               2
3       4               3
```

Here is my second table "booking" (which is showing whether taxi is booked or not via "taxiNumber/serial number")

```
id      userId          taxiNumber      servicedate             
1       2               2               201910-29
```

I tried with following code

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('taxiInfo');
$this->db->where('userId', $_POST['userId']);
$query = $this->db->get();
if ( $query->num_rows() > 0 )
    {
            $rows = $query->row_array();
             $shopchairs=$rows['totalTaxi'];
    } 
//first of all getting total taxi from db then make dynamic query   
$total=array();  //blank array  
for($i=1;$i<=$shopchairs;$i++)
                {
                    $date = date('Y-m-d');
                    $this->db->select('b.*');
                    $this->db->from('booking b');
                    $this->db->where('userId', $_POST['user_id']);
                    $this->db->where('taxiNumber', $i);
                    $this->db->where('servicedate', $date);
                    $querys = $this->db->get();
                    $res = $querys->result_array();
                    //echo "<pre>";print_R($res);
                    //exit;
                    if (empty($res)) {
                         $total['taxiNumber']=$i;
                         $total['status']="available";
                    }else
                    {
                        $total['taxiNumber']=$res['0']['taxiNumber'];
                        $total['status']="booked";
                    }   
                }
        echo "<pre>";print_R($total);
```

All result not comimg in single array ($total); Where i am wrong ?

Comment: If the query works, try `$total[]= array('taxiNumber'=>$i, 'status' =>'available');` (same for else part). Right now each loop overwrite the previous one in your array

Comment: @ Mickaël Leger : kindly explain your point or make changes in my code

Comment: What output do you get right now and what output do you want? Right now you have a $total array and in your foreach, every loop you do $total['taxiNumber'] = X and $total['status'] = Y...So at the end of your foreach you will only have a $total array with the last result of the last loop. Is this your problem ? If not, sorry but I don't understand your issue